# 3d Object Detection using the Ouster Sensor

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds, open3d

I am working on the ouster sensor in which i have to detect the 3d object .  Ouster also has the Ouster-sdk documenattion https://static.ouster.dev/sdk-docs/quickstart.html in which i have able to extract the 2d image from the ouster sensor .
My question is that how can i detect 3d object from the ouster sensor, point cloud to integrate with existing 3d object detection point cloud algorithms.
i have tried this github https://github.com/maudzung/Complex-YOLOv4-Pytorch but the issue is that i am not able to match the kitti dataset format with my ouster sensor format .

i have save the sensor file in .pcap file format but in kitti dataset they have calib, bin , image files .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Voxelnet. I think it's easy.
[Voxelnet](https://towardsdatascience.com/lidar-point-cloud-based-3d-object-detection-implementation-with-colab-part-2-of-2-f3ad55c3f38c)

And about the format,  you have to change the format to bin and image. or you have to scan and put realtime data

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30779682)